# Mostrar filas ocultas de una tabla con data-toggle="collapse" en Asp.Net Mvc

Tags: bootstrap, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Hola buen dia estoy usando data-toggle="collapse" en Asp.Net Mvc para ocultar algunas columnas de cada fila y que al momento de hacer clic en una fila se visualicen esas columnas y lo hace pero quisiera que al hacer clic se mostraran solo los datos de la fila que estoy seleccionando y no los de toda la tabla

Vista Razor

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-responsive  table-hover">

    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nombre)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.apellidopaterno)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.apellidomaterno)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.sexo)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.edad)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.telefono)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{

        <tr class="clickable" data-toggle="collapse" id="row1" data-target=".row1">

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nombre)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.apellidopaterno)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.apellidomaterno)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sexo)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.edad)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.telefono)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.matricula }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.matricula }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.matricula })
            </td>
        </tr>

            <tr class="collapse row1">
                <th>
                    carrera
                </th>
                <th>
                  semestre
                </th>
            </tr>
        <tr class="collapse row1">
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.carrera)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Semestre)
            </td>
        </tr>  


}
</table>
```

Bootstrap

```
table .collapse.in {
    display: table-row;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es debido a que en cada fila estás considerando `id="row1" data-target=".row1"` y el destino sería `<tr class="collapse row1">`.

---

Lo que podrías hacer es definir una variable que sería el índice, por ejemplo:

```
@{
    var indice = 0;
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        indice++;
        <tr class="clickable" data-toggle="collapse" id="row@(indice)" data-target=".row@(indice)">

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nombre)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.apellidopaterno)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.apellidomaterno)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sexo)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.edad)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.telefono)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.matricula }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.matricula }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.matricula })
            </td>
        </tr>

            <tr class="collapse row@(indice)">
                <th>
                    carrera
                </th>
                <th>
                  semestre
                </th>
            </tr>

            <tr class="collapse row@(indice)">
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.carrera)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Semestre)
            </td>
        </tr>       
    }
}
```